# How to install Windows 10 in dual boot with Linux (distinct drives)?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, debian-jessie

**Premise**: I am aware it's perfectly possible to install Windows 10 and Ubuntu/Debian **afterwards** on the same drive (without ending up in a corrupted bootloader), but my current set up is different.

**My current setup**:

- Laptop with traditional HDD with Debian 8 installed on a fully-encrypted (LVM) internal disk
- The laptop has a Usb 3.0 port (and 2 Usb 2.0 ports)
- I have a usb 2.0 drive with Windows 10 bootable installer
- I have a usb 3.0 (type C compatible) SSD where I want to install WIndoed 10

**The desired final setup**:

- **Windows 10 installed in the external SSD**
- **Windows 10 shall dual boot with Debian**: either offering me to dual boot Debian or Windows 10 whenever the external SSD was connected on system boot, or alternatively boot directly Windows 10 whenever the external SSD was connection on system boot.

How do I obtain the final result, making sure **not** ending up with the Debian installation **broken** (or broken bootloader)?

Comment: If Windows was already installed,it would be simpler, because Grub-loader have mechanism to use the bootloader of Windows, so that you may choose the OS in the grub. If you install windows after, you need to change something in the bootconfiguration of Windows by reinstalling grub e.g easybcd.

Comment: @GiaRui thanks for your advice. can you confirm it's actually doable and safe to fix the boot loader after installing Windows 10 after Debian and that's actually possible on 2 different hard drives?
If you think you can clarify these questions with some "HOW TO", feel free to answer (I'll be glad to accept your answer ;) )

Answer (score 1):

It's a try, however I experienced the same Problems by booting from media in Bios/Uefi or to install first Linux and then Windows.

1 - If Secureboot is active, boot and disable UEFI(or Secureboot) and 
    enable Legacy Bios mode to boot.

2 - Install Windows on the desired Harddrive.

3 - Boot(bios) from the harddrive with Linux and install GrubCustomizer.
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
    (if not in the Repository)

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer 

start GrubCustomizer, choose Windows from the Bootlist and shift it to 
the first place as you desire it.
```

4 - (If 3 didn't work)In Windows use EasyBCD to set the boot-configuration.

5 - Or instead of 4, use the Boot-repair-tool on boot then choose 
    recommended repair.

Here an explain for bios or uefi:

> UEFI: To prevent Windows Setup or Windows PE from booting in BIOS mode, >remove the bootmgr file on the root of the media.
>
> BIOS: To prevent Windows Setup or Windows PE from booting in UEFI mode, >remove the efi folder on the root of the media.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll try as soon as possible (not  yet sure when I can do this) and then accept the answer / provide a feedback. By boot-repair-tool you mean https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ ?

Comment: Yes I meant the same tool.